# How can I reflect a point about a line in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am drawing a line using the line renderer in the following way:

```
  public class MyLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour {
    LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    public Vector3 p0, p1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
      lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
      lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;

      lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, p0);
      lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, p1);

    }
 }
```

From the image below, the line `P0P1` is known and so is point A. How can a point B, which is the reflection of A about the line `P0P1` be found?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [`Vector3.Reflect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html).

- Take the vector from `a` to `p0` and call that your `inDirection`
- Take the vector from `p0` to `p1` and call that your `inNormal`
- Plug these values in: `Vector3.Reflect(p0 - a, p1 - p0)`

The above call gives you a vector from `p0` to `b`, so you can find `b` as follows:

```
Vector3 b = p0 + Vector3.Reflect(p0 - a, p1 - p0);
```

To explain what's happening here, we're imagining that `inNormal` is the normal vector of a plane, then reflecting a vector against that plane. If all you care about is reflecting across a line, you could actually set that plane anywhere along the line and get the same result.

[image: Vector3 reflection diagram]

If you're working in 2D, there is a similar `Vector2.Reflect` function. This works for any number of dimensions as long as you have an appropriate vector class.

Comment: I tried the code you provided, but it's not reflecting the point to the right place as in the image provided

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the normal ? (no pun intended)

Vector3.Reflect(p0 - a, (p1 - p0).normalized)

Answer (score 0):

For XZ coordinates, try this code;

```
public class Symmetry: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform p0;
    public Transform p1;
    public Transform pointA;
    public Transform pointB;

    float m, x1, z1, x2, z2, x3, z3, u, v;

    float targetPosX, targetPosZ;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
      CalculateSymmetry();
    }

    private void CalculateSymmetry()
    {
      x1 = p0.position.x;
      z1 = p0.position.z;
      x2 = p1.position.x;
      z2 = p1.position.z;
      x3 = pointA.position.x;
      z3 = pointA.position.z;

      m = ((x3 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (z3 - z1) * (z2 - z1)) / ((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (z2 - z1) * (z2 - z1));

      u = x1 + m * (x2 - x1);
      v = z1 + m * (z2 - z1);

      targetPosX = 2 * u - x3;
      targetPosZ = 2 * v - z3;

      pointB.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(targetPosX, pointB.position.y, targetPosZ);
    }
}
```

**Explanation;**
pointA: A point in your pic.
pointB: Symmetry of A point (B in your pic)
p0: Line Start
p1: Line End

ps. I am using game objects. You can change it for yourself.